# How can I circumvent server-side model validation errors when I have Edit and New forms on a single asp core 2.1 razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

Using Asp Core 2.1 Razor pages to build a single page application. My Edit and New functionality is on one page.

Razor Page:

```
@page
@model EditNewTestModel
@{
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            <input asp-for="NewXyz.Title" />
            <input asp-for="NewXyz.Description" />
            <input asp-for="NewXyz.PropertyA" />
            <input asp-for="NewXyz.PropertyB" />
            <button>Submit New</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form method="post">
            <input asp-for="EditXyz.Title" />
            <input asp-for="EditXyz.Description" />
            <input asp-for="EditXyz.PropertyA" />
            <input asp-for="EditXyz.PropertyB" />
            <button>Submit Edit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

The Model with data attributes for validation:

```
public class FormXyz
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the .cs for the razor page:

```
namespace razorpageTest.Pages
{
    public class EditNewTestModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        [BindProperty]
        public FormXyz NewXyz { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public FormXyz EditXyz { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var a = NewXyz;
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is when I submit the "New" form the ModelState.IsValid is false because for some reason the Title and Description fields are being prepended to the list of keys as seen in the screen shot below. Both their values show as null even though they weren't submitted. also as a test I entered values in the Edit fields and the keys are still null. When I remove the BindProperty Attribute from the "Edit" property the extra properties are not posted but I loose the Edit functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the properties of your edit and new models are the same, just bind one `FormXyz` property to the page, and either post to different handlers, or check to see if the key property has a value. If it does, you are editing an existing item. If not, you are creating a new one.

At the moment, both `FormXyz` properties are taking part in model binding. One is not populated (the EditXyz property in this example), so its properties end up with default values. Strings default to null but they are required, so they get added to the ModelState dictionary errors. Ints default to 0, so they will have a value and pass the `Required` test. Check this out by making `PropertyA` nullable, and you will end up with that added to the errors too.

Or just create one page for create, and one for edit to reduce confusion.